# <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h> file not found Google Maps SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, ios5, google-maps-sdk-ios

Yesterday I recived an email from google saying that I could acces to the map api for ios, I generated my key from the app console and I follow the steps of https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start but xcode throw this error.

```
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h> //file not found
```

Thanks for your support.

It is normal that appears the Headers executable instead of the folder?

[image]

SOLVED!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure you unzip the SDK with something which understands symbolic links.

`GoogleMaps.framework/Headers` is a symbolic link to `GoogleMaps.framework/Versions/A/Headers`.

When I unzip it on my Mac the symbolic link is set up correctly. But when I unzip it on my PC instead of symbolic links I get text files which just contain the path (eg `Versions/Current/Headers`).

If you unzip on a PC and then copy the folder to your Mac (or unzip using some other method which doesn't create symbolic links), then you will get the error you see.

Comment: In my case the missing symbolic link was coming from cordova framework. So I resolved by removing/adding the relative plugin with cordova on Mac: `cordova plugin remove ...` and `cordova plugin add ...`

Answer (score 20):

**1)** Extract the subfolder A in version and I renamed it to
`GoogleMaps.framework`

**2)** Copy this folder to your project folder.

[image]

**3)** Add it to your Frameworks group in the project

[image]

**4)** Import to AppDelegate as `#import "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h"`

Comment: Did you unzip the SDK with something which doesn't understand symbolic links? Or maybe unzip it on a PC and then copy the folder to your Mac? GoogleMaps.framework/Headers is a symbolic link to GoogleMaps.framework/Versions/A/Headers. When I unzip on my Mac the symbolic link is set up correctly. But when I unzip on my PC instead of symbolic links I get text files which just contain the path (eg 'Versions/Current/Headers'). This would probably cause the kind of error you're seeing.

Comment: I dowloaded from a pc but I extracted it in my Mac

Comment: Ok now I checked it and this was my error, thanks, modify to an answer to set it as the correct answer.

Comment: Hi Fernando, no worries :) I posted it as a separate answer.

Comment: It's only a temporary solution. When I reopen the project the problem persists and I have to do everything again to make it work. @ƒernando Valle

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

> Drag the **GoogleMaps.framework** bundle to the Frameworks group of your project. When prompted, select Copy items into destination group's folder.

You have to copy the unzipped folder "**GoogleMaps.framework**" into **XCode**.

Then follow steps 3 & 4

> 3.Right-click **GoogleMaps.framework** in your project, and select Show In Finder.         
>  4.Drag the **GoogleMaps.bundle** from the Resources folder to your project. We suggest putting it in the Frameworks group. When prompted, ensure Copy items into destination group's folder is not selected.

If still not working try adding manually GoogleMaps.framework in the Build Phases tab->**Link Binary** with **Libraries**

Comment: It does not work, I follow every step as you said and appear the same problem. I tried to link the library too butothing happen. What should appear in GoogleMaps.framework? when I import in Frameworks it only show me "Headers" (file not folder) may be it is the problem.

Comment: You should have the GoogleMaps.framework (which contain Headers) and GoogleMaps.bundle.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the first few steps you need:

- Download `GoogleMaps-iOS-1.1.0.zip` from their site
- Unzip the file. You now have a `GoogleMaps-iOS-1.1.0` folder
- In that folder you have a `GoogleMaps.framework` folder.
- Copy or move the `GoogleMaps.framework` folder to inside your project folder (in Finder).
- Drag the `GoogleMaps.framework` folder onto your `Frameworks` group in Xcode.
- In the options sheet, uncheck "Copy items into destination group's folder". Make sure your target is checked in "Add to targets". Click OK.
- (Note that you can also do this the other way, by not copying it into your project folder and checking "Copy items into destination group's folder". Xcode will copy the folder itself.)
- Import using `#import "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h"`. The angle bracket usually work too, but in this case it should use quotes.

You should end up with a golden toolbox icon:

[image]

Using an `#import` with angle brackets should search the system frameworks, then inside your project folder, but to be safe try it with quotes.

Comment: It does not work, I follow every step as you said and appear the same problem. What should appear in GoogleMaps.framework? when I import in Frameworks it only show me "Headers" (file not folder) may be it is the problem.

Comment: If you copy the "Headers" folder to Xcode, you will get a group called "Headers", which looks like a folder. If you copy the "GoogleMaps.framework" folder, you should get a (gold toolbox) frameworks icon. Are you sure you're copying the right folder? My advice would be to start from the beginning (downloading the zip file) and use a new project to see which step isn't working.

Comment: Yes, when I copy GoogleMaps.framework folder it appears like a "tools box" in xcode. I tried start with new proyect several times, downloading the zip and following every step. The thing that I dont see good is when I copy it only appear Headers executable file instead of the folder with all the headers like in the other frameworks. I will edit the post adding an image for show you how it appears.

Comment: That's very strange. It could be that there's something wrong with linked files on you computer. You could try starting from the sample project in the "GoogleMapsSDKDemos" folder. If that works, transfer your project over to it. Check if the headers appears correctly in that project.

Answer (score 2):

I've been struggling with this issue for hours; I'm using CocoaPods, Swift and Xcode 6.1.1. I followed all the steps for including GoogleMaps in my project carefully, tried many different things like removing symbolic links in the downloaded package or manually linking the binaries in build phases or trying `#include "GoogleMaps.h"`, `#include "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h"` and `"#include <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>` in my bridge file, none of that worked... Finally used CocoaPods instead of including the framework myself and it worked! Hope it helps someone out there:

In the Podfile:

`pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-SDK', '~> 1.9.2'`

And in your Bridge file:

`#import "GoogleMaps.h"`

Answer (score 1):

the GoogleMaps framework is probably not in the Library folder but in the same directory like all other project files. I this case you have to write `#import "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h` or `#import "GoogleMaps.h"`

Comment: It didnt solve my problem I will go back in other moment to try solve this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I added the framework to my files folder and when I write  `#import <GoogleMaps...` the autocomplete show me `<GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps` but nothing more, I cant add GoogleMaps.h

Answer (score 0):

make sure you upgrade to the latest sdk.
v1 and v3 were different.
had trouble getting v1 to work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've forgot after change Podfile, you have to run

> pod update

then rerun react-native run-ios

Answer (score 0):

Its better install Pod for google map, Just add google maps into pod.
Note if you don't have pod file in your project folder ios/ then do below steps
pod init

the add below code in your pod file

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'YourAppTarget' do
  pod 'GoogleMaps'  # <~~ remove this line if you do not want to support GoogleMaps on iOS
end
# pre_install do |installer|
   # copied from https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2926
   # workaround for https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3289
  #  def installer.verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies; end
# end

target 'YourAppTarget-tvOS' do

end
```

Do not forget to add AirGoogleMaps to your project directory from 
node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/ios

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
```

add above the **RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED or Debug** in the Appdelegate.m

then add +

```
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"IOS_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY"];
```

then add the Below Lines into **podfile** above the **use_native_modules!**

```
rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
```

This will work

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to your pod file

rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path

pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 6.1.0'

after that run
pod install

Answer (score -2):

This answer will also might help you. The above all answers are not worked for me at last after a long time i found like this

```
# import "GoogleMapsM4B/GoogleMaps.h"
```

Use like this it definitely solves your problem

Comment: GoogleMapsM4B is for premium users (as clearly indicated in installation guides in Google Maps SDK fro IOS)