# Xcode: ld: framework not found AVFoundation

Tags: ios, xcode, avfoundation, xcode7, watchos-2

Can anybody give me some hints on this frustrating problem.

I added WatchKit OS2 to current iOS project in Xcode 7.1.1 and when i emulate the WatchOS and iOS in simulator everything works fine.

But when i try to build it for device i get this error for Watch App Extension:

```
ld: framework not found AVFoundation
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I googled a lot and can't find a solution to this.

Comment: it mention avfoundation framework is not found, did you added that

Comment: @KishoreKumar Yes, in embedded binaries, linked frameworks and libraries i added AVFoundation.framework but still appears the same error. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130629/framework-not-found-googlemaps-sdk-in-ios refer this link bro may be you will get someidea

Comment: @KishoreKumar Thanks for the link man, i got it working!

Comment: fine ;).................

Answer (score 0):

Let me introduce my problem. Hope to give you some inspiration.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]