# ios Module 'GoogleMapsBase' not found

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

[image: Error]

[image: pods version]

[image: Pod Structure]

I have updated my pods to the latest GoogleSDK which now has [separate cocoapods](https://developers.google.com/places/migrate-to-v2). After I have successfully updated my pods I am having issue with the module **GoogleMapsBase** which cannot be found and as a result I think it cannot build module **GooglePlaces**. I am working in Xcode 7.3.1 using ObjectiveC. I am having a similar issue like [this](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/issues/19) but it is fixed in version 2.0.1 and I am using version 2.0.1 as well.

Comment: I solved my issue by [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130629/framework-not-found-googlemaps-sdk-in-ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130629/framework-not-found-googlemaps-sdk-in-ios)，Don't pod，Don't pod。

Comment: Have you tried to edit your `PodFile` in your project directory? This file defines your project's dependencies. Specify your target name and the name of pods that come with the Places API for IOS. After that try to run `pod install` command. This will install the API's specified in the `Podfile` along with any dependencies they may have. Note that Google Maps SDK for IOs requires atleast Xcode 7.0 with a target SDK of 8.0 or later.

Comment: @d.datul1990 I have also tried this but the issue was still there. My Xcode version is 7.3.1 and target sdk is 8.0

Comment: would you please show us your podfile structure

Comment: I'm experiencing this as well when just importing GooglePlaces 2.0.1. What specifically was done to fix this?

Comment: @Astoria I have added the Podfile Structure.
This is the current version but as you can see that the commented portion was the older version.

Comment: @blahartinger the workaround for me was to stick to 1.13.2 because of the workload.