# Frameworks Added to cocoapod getiing import issue "Framework not found"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, google-maps, cocoapods

This is my podfile:

```
`target 'ROC' do
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
pod 'INTULocationManager'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'FSMediaPicker'
pod 'IQDropDownTextField'
pod 'Google/Analytics'
pod 'Google/SignIn'
pod 'Appboy-iOS-SDK', '~>2.22'

end
```

`

> Now I open podfile and added **pod 'GoogleMaps'**
>     **pod 'GooglePlaces'** then update pod.
>   I can see googleMaps framework in project nevigator but cant import because of error Googlemap not found.same with APPboy. What to do help please.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19946503/5832311):

1. Click on your project (**targets**)
2. Click on **Build Settings**
3. Under **Framework search paths** (set your framework path)

Following information for **getting framework search paths**

1. Right click on your framework folder (for ex: GoogleMaps.framework)
2. select **Get info**
3. copy the path from **General->where** and paste this path in your framework search path (path should contain in single line)

You can also try to reinstall the SDK. Just make sure you followed the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start) properly.