# Adding external framework in Xcode 8.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I try to add FacebookSDK framework and GoogleSDK api. But when i adding these kind of framework in xcode by dragging/add from target.***I got error.**ld: framework not found GoogleAppUtilities
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)***
 and Pod installation got error too...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7L5U.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZoe8.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Framework not found GoogleMaps sdk in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130629/framework-not-found-googlemaps-sdk-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

You should try pod for installation these type of framework because download SDK for each site (fb,Google) having all network stuff for working independently.
So when you add or use any of two framework in same project they conflict with each other. **Pod is the best way to manage framework dependency.**

Comment: I tried by pod installation. Installation was done but no luck.......GOT ERROR......

Comment: first delete these four in you project root folder 1, podfile.lock, 2. pod folder, 3 newly created workspace 4. Podfile. after that init pod again in your project and add all required pod link in your pod file and then run pod install command.

Comment: I got warning and xcworkspace is not created . Warning : "[!] Pods written in Swift can only be integrated as frameworks; add `use_frameworks!` to your Podfile or target to opt into using it. The Swift Pods being used are: FacebookCore and FacebookLogin"