# iOS project building get warning: file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x56 0x65 ... ) which is not the architecture being linked (arm64)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

- I have made my own static library named uexLiving.a. And this static library includes two framework (not created by me) named NBPClientLib.framework and UPnP.framework.
- After that I am trying to use this static library in my another iOS project. But it is building unsuccessfully.
- The warning is

> [2015-08-06 21:21:56,351] DEBUG SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 //opt/applog//114/458/28/11445828-iphone - ld: warning: ignoring file /ram_disk/temp/XO8Nv2tIc9JI/AppCanPlugin/AppCanPlugin/uexFrameworks/NBPClientLib.framework/NBPClientLib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x56 0x65 0x72 0x73 0x69 0x6F 0x6E 0x73 0x2F 0x43 0x75 0x72 0x72 0x65 0x6E 0x74 ) which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): /ram_disk/temp/XO8Nv2tIc9JI/AppCanPlugin/AppCanPlugin/uexFrameworks/NBPClientLib.framework/NBPClientLib
>
> [2015-08-06 21:21:56,351] DEBUG SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 //opt/applog//114/458/28/11445828-iphone - ld: warning: ignoring file /ram_disk/temp/XO8Nv2tIc9JI/AppCanPlugin/AppCanPlugin/uexFrameworks/UPnP.framework/UPnP, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x56 0x65 0x72 0x73 0x69 0x6F 0x6E 0x73 0x2F 0x43 0x75 0x72 0x72 0x65 0x6E 0x74 ) which is not the architecture being linked (armv7):
>
> [2015-08-06 21:21:56,353] DEBUG SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 //opt/applog//114/458/28/11445828-iphone - ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file /ram_disk/temp/XO8Nv2tIc9JI/AppCanPlugin/AppCanPlugin/uexFrameworks/NBPClientLib.framework/NBPClientLib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x56 0x65 0x72 0x73 0x69 0x6F 0x6E 0x73 0x2F 0x43 0x75 0x72 0x72 0x65 0x6E 0x74 ) which is not the architecture being linked (arm64):

- So I got the error:

> [2015-08-06 21:21:56,351] DEBUG SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 //opt/applog//114/458/28/11445828-iphone - Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>   [2015-08-06 21:21:56,352] DEBUG SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 //opt/applog//114/458/28/11445828-iphone -   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_N_ClientLib", referenced from:
>   [2015-08-06 21:21:56,352] DEBUG SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 //opt/applog//114/458/28/11445828-iphone -       objc-class-ref in libuexLiving.a(EUExLiving.o)
>   [2015-08-06 21:21:56,352] DEBUG SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 //opt/applog//114/458/28/11445828-iphone - ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
>   [2015-08-06 21:21:56,352] DEBUG SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 //opt/applog//114/458/28/11445828-iphone - clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> [2015-08-06 21:21:56,353] DEBUG SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 //opt/applog//114/458/28/11445828-iphone - Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   [2015-08-06 21:21:56,353] DEBUG SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 //opt/applog//114/458/28/11445828-iphone -   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_N_ClientLib", referenced from:
>   [2015-08-06 21:21:56,353] DEBUG SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 //opt/applog//114/458/28/11445828-iphone -       objc-class-ref in libuexLiving.a(EUExLiving.o)
>   [2015-08-06 21:21:56,353] DEBUG SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 //opt/applog//114/458/28/11445828-iphone - ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
>   [2015-08-06 21:21:56,353] DEBUG SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 //opt/applog//114/458/28/11445828-iphone - clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

- What's wrong with this two framework? How can I resolve this problem?

#### Update

I use the terminal to check the architecture of the framework. It shows that

> Zemans-Macbook:1 nathan$ file UPnP
>
> UPnP: Mach-O universal binary with 4 architectures
>
> UPnP (for architecture armv7):    current ar archive random library
>
> UPnP (for architecture i386): current ar archive random library
>
> UPnP (for architecture x86_64):   current ar archive random library
>
> UPnP (for architecture arm64):    current ar archive random library
>
> Zemans-Macbook:1 nathan$ file NBPClientLib
>
> NBPClientLib: Mach-O universal binary with 4 architectures
>
> NBPClientLib (for architecture armv7):    current ar archive random library
>
> NBPClientLib (for architecture i386): current ar archive random library
>
> NBPClientLib (for architecture x86_64):   current ar archive random library
>
> NBPClientLib (for architecture arm64):    current ar archive random library

Comment: How can a static library contain frameworks?

Comment: The static library(also means the .a file) does not contain the framework, just import it.

Comment: Hmm, not really.  It can be compiled to use the framework, sure, but the application/dylib/framework that uses the static library will have to link with these frameworks.

Comment: Yes. But the compiler shows that the framework do not support architecture armv7 and arm64.

Comment: Well it sounds like you know the reason for the error message.  I assume you've checked the CPU architectures compiled into these other frameworks?

Comment: I use the terminal to check the two frameworks. And I have put the information above.

Comment: I don't see information about `NBPClientLib.framework` etc?

Comment: It is very strange that the two frameworks support armv7 and arm64, but the compiler still shows that waring.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot it. It's same.

Comment: Zemans-Macbook:1 nathan$ file NBPClientLib 
NBPClientLib: Mach-O universal binary with 4 architectures
NBPClientLib (for architecture armv7): current ar archive random library
NBPClientLib (for architecture i386): current ar archive random library
NBPClientLib (for architecture x86_64): current ar archive random library
NBPClientLib (for architecture arm64): current ar archive random library

Comment: This may be a problem with GNU binutils being in `$PATH`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62437450/14558