# Add google maps linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps

I added the framework version 1,9,1 and follow the instructions to do the right, but after the start of the project, Xcode gives an error

```
ld: framework not found GoogleMaps
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I do not know why he wrote that the framework is not found i added in `appdelegate`.h

```
#import  <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
```

and he did not get an error that the file is not found, the framework itself, I added to the rest of the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Have you properly installed the SDK? This error could also be seen if the SDK was not properly installed. To quote the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021006/googlemaps-googlemaps-h-file-not-found-google-maps-sdk-for-ios):

"*Make sure you unzip the SDK with something which understands symbolic links.
GoogleMaps.framework/Headers is a symbolic link to GoogleMaps.framework/Versions/A/Headers.
When I unzip it on my Mac the symbolic link is set up correctly. But when I unzip it on my PC instead of symbolic links I get text files which just contain the path (eg Versions/Current/Headers).
If you unzip on a PC and then copy the folder to your Mac (or unzip using some other method which doesn't create symbolic links), then you will get the error you see.*"