# iOS - #import "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h" not found

Tags: ios, google-maps

I'm sorry, I'm newbie in iOS development.
I use library from [here](https://github.com/ManoMarks/demos) to get direction of two place in Google Maps. I have ever used Google Maps. After I import Google Maps Framework, I still get error...

This is the problem :
[image]

***How to import get GoogleMaps header ?***

Comment: Go into Terminal, "`cd`" to the folder where your Google Maps framework is found, do a "`ls -lR`" on that framework and let me know if you see a "`GoogleMaps.h`" file in the list of files that shows up.

Comment: you should add GoogleMaps lib header folder to your project

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I don't find it

Comment: Thanks, all! I have found the problem. I copy corrupted Google Maps framework so I get this problem

Comment: [I already answered here pls find][1]

# import "GoogleMapsM4B/GoogleMaps.h"



  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021006/googlemaps-googlemaps-h-file-not-found-google-maps-sdk-for-ios/30866561#30866561

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be an issue of you **not** copying the frameworks to the project folder, and then after adding the GoogleMaps framework maybe you moved the framework file on your computer to a new location?

Try deleting the framework from your project and then adding the framework again by going to your Project's Build Setting --> Build Phases and dragging the framework into that window.

Also, perform a Project Clean, and make sure that if you have an iOS Simulator running (in any project) to stop it and close it.

Sometimes this causes Xcode to freeze the update process within the coding.

Comment: I copy corrupted Google Maps framework. So, I get this problem

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the updated Googlemaps sdk for iOS and search something like GoogleMaps.Framework in the downloaded zip file
2. Drag the GoogleMaps.Framework into your project

Comment: where cn one download this?

Comment: I found out. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start

Answer (score 0):

Removing and adding Google Map SDK again works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

running pod update and install fixes the issue.

```
cd ios

pod update
```

Answer (score -1):

```
# import "GoogleMapsM4B/GoogleMaps.h"
```

It reads first framework name GoogleMapsM4B and the then a class GoogleMaps.h now googlemaps.h consists of all class .
then u van access the all class like GMSMapview etc.